# Sorting Json n PHp

Tags: php, arrays, json

Sorting Json n PHp

```
Array ( 
    [status] => 1 
    [message] => Product Search.
    [data] => Array ( 
        [total_records] => 30 
        [records] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [id] => 278 
                [name] => 120L Double Door Fridge 
                [thumbnail] => 1598898253.jpeg 
                [price] => 16789 
            )
            [1] => Array ( 
                [id] => 9737 
                [name] => 324 liter Double Door Fridge 
                [thumbnail] => 4-324%20liter%20Double%20Door%20Fridge.jpg 
                [price] => 28791 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Below is the Code that i have with no luck,

I want the each product to be shown with name, thumbnail and price

Please guide, any one can guide

```
$div='<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 box-price" style="text-align:center">';
            if(is_array($value)){
                display_array_recursive($value);
            }else{
            
                if($key=='thumbnail'){
                    $div.= '    <img src="https://test.com/GameGuys/Act1/'. $value.'" width="300"  height="300"><br><br>';  
                }
                if($key=='name') {
                    $div.= '  <strong>  '. $value.'</strong><br>';
                }
                //echo ' '$key.'--'.$value.'<br>';
                
                if($key=='price') {
                    $div.= '  Rs<span>'.$value .' </span><br>';
                }
                    echo $div ;
                }
                $div.= '</div>';    
            }   
        }   
    }
display_array_recursive($json_array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to understand your Php code.

Here is a simple way to do what you actually want:

```
<?php 

foreach($array['data']['records'] as $value){

?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 box-price" style="text-align:center">
    <img src="https://fillmmaka.com/GameGuys/Act1/<?php echo $value['thumbnail'];?>" width="300"  height="300"><br><br>
    <strong><?php echo $value['name'];?></strong>
    Rs<span><?php echo $value['price'];?></span><br>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Output: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00ec6eb7a5af680886eb6f0069af5aaabe080d89

Comment: Hi, can you guide how to add pagination and parse total_records

Comment: @LgsSidhu  for that please ask a separate question.

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66345026/json-post-reponse-pagnination

Answer (score 0):

Half your code example is missing, however, this is how I have understood it...

```php
$input = [
  'status' => true,
  'message' => 'Product Search.',
  'data' => [
    'total_records' => 30,
    'records' => [
      [
        'id' => 278,
        'name' => '120L Double Door Fridge',
        'thumbnail' => '1598898253.jpeg',
        'price' => 16789
      ],
      [
        'id' => 9737,
        'name' => '324 liter Double Door Fridge',
        'thumbnail' => '4-324%20liter%20Double%20Door%20Fridge.jpg',
        'price' => 28791
      ]
    ]
  ]
];


if ( $input[ 'status' ] && !empty( $input[ 'data' ][ 'records' ] ) ) {
  foreach ( $input[ 'data' ][ 'records' ] as $product ) {
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 box-price" style="text-align:center">
        <?php if ( !empty( $product[ 'thumbnail' ] ) ): ?>
          <img src="https://fillmmaka.com/GameGuys/Act1/<?= $product[ 'thumbnail' ]; ?>" width="300"  height="300"><br><br>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( !empty( $product[ 'name' ] ) ): ?>
          <strong><?= $product[ 'name' ] ;?></strong><br>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ( !empty( $product[ 'price' ] ) ): ?>
          Rs<span><?= $product[ 'price' ] ;?></span><br>
        <?php endif ?>
      </div>
    <?php
  }
}
```

You can turn this into a recursive function if you wish...

```php
function display_recursive_products( $products, $echo = true ) {
  ob_start();
  if ( $products ) {
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {
      ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 box-price" style="text-align:center">
          <?php if ( !empty( $product[ 'thumbnail' ] ) ): ?>
            <img src="https://fillmmaka.com/GameGuys/Act1/<?= $product[ 'thumbnail' ]; ?>" width="300"  height="300"><br><br>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if ( !empty( $product[ 'name' ] ) ): ?>
            <strong><?= $product[ 'name' ] ;?></strong><br>
          <?php endif ?>
          <?php if ( !empty( $product[ 'price' ] ) ): ?>
            Rs<span><?= $product[ 'price' ] ;?></span><br>
          <?php endif ?>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
  }
  $html = ob_get_clean();

  if ( $echo ) {
    echo $html;
  } else {
    return $html;
  }
}
```

Usage would be something like:

```php
display_recursive_products( $input[ 'data' ][ 'records' ] );
```

See it in action here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40f55cc1e2e0f95b90cd3541951c89fbccdc5a15

Comment: This worked but can we add pagination to that?

Comment: @LgsSidhu adding pagination is totally seperate question, you would need to attempt this yourself and then open a new question if you are struggling. StackOverflow is not a free programming service.